# Programmatically Focus on on a webview (WKWebView)

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am working on a macOS app in which I am using a WKWebview to show web content.

However, after I clicked on another application and then click on my macOS app, I need to click twice on the Webview window, as it doesn't get activated by hovering my mouse over it.
It doesn't listen to events until I click the webview window.

I'm new to Swift and being used to Javascript I would just add a 'mouseenter' listener to the macOS window to focus the webview.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this?